# how to script ttl print keycode = 40?

Tags: ttl

i think my source tetaterm have problem and i dont understand

my source tetaterm

```
sendln ' sqlplus /'
sendln ' select * from table where item ='examp';'
```

result:

```
<<<sendln ' select * from table where item ='>>> examp';'
```

but i want display screen tetaterm is :

```
select * from table where item ='examp';
```

so , how to script mayby understand charater " ' " in tetaterm
because tetarem starting by ' and end ' ,
i dont display ' in program teraterm